# First time use of God gem, not shutting down deamons

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resque

This is my first time using God gem.  When I run the command `god terminate` it is not shutting down the existing tasks. So the next time I run god script again it just doubles.

I saw the sample script Resque has for terminating Rogue spawns, but don't fully understand how to modify for my script.

commands I run

```
god -c config/resque.god
god -c config/stale.god
```

My resque.god file:

```
RAILS_ROOT = File.dirname(File.dirname(__FILE__))

God.watch do |w|
    w.name          = "android_msg"
    w.group         = "resque-group"
    w.interval      = 30.seconds
    w.start         = "cd #{RAILS_ROOT} && rake resque:work QUEUE='android_message'"
    w.start_grace   = 10.seconds

    # restart if memory gets too high
    w.transition(:up, :restart) do |on|
        on.condition(:memory_usage) do |c|
        c.above = 350.megabytes
        c.times = 2
        end
    end

    # determine the state on startup
    w.transition(:init, { true => :up, false => :start }) do |on|
      on.condition(:process_running) do |c|
        c.running = true
      end
    end

    # determine when process has finished starting
    w.transition([:start, :restart], :up) do |on|
      on.condition(:process_running) do |c|
        c.running = true
        c.interval = 5.seconds
      end

      # failsafe
      on.condition(:tries) do |c|
        c.times = 5
        c.transition = :start
        c.interval = 5.seconds
      end
    end

    # start if process is not running
    w.transition(:up, :start) do |on|
        on.condition(:process_running) do |c|
        c.running = false
    end
  end
end


God.watch do |w|
    w.name          = "apn_sender"
    w.group         = "resque-group"
    w.interval      = 30.seconds
    w.start         = "cd #{RAILS_ROOT} && rake apn:sender"
    w.start_grace   = 10.seconds

    # restart if memory gets too high
    w.transition(:up, :restart) do |on|
        on.condition(:memory_usage) do |c|
        c.above = 350.megabytes
        c.times = 2
        end
    end

    # determine the state on startup
    w.transition(:init, { true => :up, false => :start }) do |on|
      on.condition(:process_running) do |c|
        c.running = true
      end
    end

    # determine when process has finished starting
    w.transition([:start, :restart], :up) do |on|
      on.condition(:process_running) do |c|
        c.running = true
        c.interval = 5.seconds
      end

      # failsafe
      on.condition(:tries) do |c|
        c.times = 5
        c.transition = :start
        c.interval = 5.seconds
      end
    end

    # start if process is not running
    w.transition(:up, :start) do |on|
        on.condition(:process_running) do |c|
        c.running = false
    end
  end
end
```

stale.god

```
# This will ride alongside god and kill any rogue stale worker
# processes. Their sacrifice is for the greater good.

WORKER_TIMEOUT = 60 * 10 # 10 minutes

Thread.new do
  loop do
    begin
      `ps -e -o pid,command | grep [r]esque`.split("\n").each do |line|
        parts   = line.split(' ')
        next if parts[-2] != "at"
        started = parts[-1].to_i
        elapsed = Time.now - Time.at(started)

        if elapsed >= WORKER_TIMEOUT
          ::Process.kill('USR1', parts[0].to_i)
        end
      end
    rescue
      # don't die because of stupid exceptions
      nil
    end

    sleep 30
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do:

```
god -c config/resque.god ;; starts god with the given config
god load config/stale.god ;; loads the given config into an already running god instance
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command didn't work for me:

```
god load config/stale.god
```

After digging around, I found that it could just be required at the top of `resque.god`

```
require 'stale.god'
```